# How to deserialise XML with element prefixes in ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-deserialization

I've come across an annoying problem where I am trying to deserialise an XML payload for one of my controllers, but the payload could either have no namespacing or have namespace prefixes on all elements.

I have tried adding XML attributes to my model with `Namespace = ""` in an attempt to have the model not care, but this did not work. I have also tried setting the default namespace on my XmlSerialiser to `""` but this didn't help. I also tried the `[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]` attribute and had no luck.

Below is an example of the the two different payloads I could receive, in case I wasn't clear in my description.

`<ex:root namespace:ex="http://example.com/ns">
   <ex:element>Example</ex:element>
   <ex:secondElement>Example2</ex:secondElement>
 </ex:root>`

`<root>
   <element>Example</element>
   <secondElement>Example</secondElement>
 </root>`

And below is the model for that payload that I would be trying to deserialise to

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
   [XmlElement("element")]
   public string Element {get; set;}

   [XmlElement("secondElement")]
   public string SecondElement {get; set;}
}
```

I sincerely apologise if this has been answered somewhere else but I have tried the solutions to every question I could find relevant to my issue and had no success.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Fixed namespaced XML example

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how have you tried to deserialize, but something like this will work:

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("sample.xml");
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
var obj = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two different possible elements that may appear first inside the root, we need to express that choice (and similarly for the second element). I played around with trying to write the correct code directly but failed, so instead I first wrote a schema to express that was wanted and then used the [`xsd` command line tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate the C# code<sup>1</sup>.

First, the main schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ex="http://example.com/ns" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/ns" />
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="ex:element" />
                    <xs:element name="element" >
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="ex:secondElement"  />
                    <xs:element name="secondElement" />
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And then we need another schema to describe the `ns` schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/ns"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://example.com/ns"
    xmlns:mstns="http://example.com/ns"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:element name="element"/>
    <xs:element name="secondElement"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And then we run `xsd /classes XmlFile1.xsd XMLSchema1.xsd` (assuming that's the names given to the two `xsd` files.

This spits out a class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class root {

    private object itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    private object item1Field;

    private Item1ChoiceType item1ElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("element", typeof(object))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("element", typeof(object), Namespace="http://example.com/ns")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("secondElement", typeof(object), Namespace="http://example.com/ns")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("secondElement", typeof(object))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("Item1ElementName")]
    public object Item1 {
        get {
            return this.item1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.item1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public Item1ChoiceType Item1ElementName {
        get {
            return this.item1ElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.item1ElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    element,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("http://example.com/ns:element")]
    element1,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum Item1ChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("http://example.com/ns:secondElement")]
    secondElement,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("secondElement")]
    secondElement1,
}
```

Which you can probably edit/adjust to fit your exact needs. E.g. I don't think the types used here (`object`) are exactly ideal, and can probably be adjusted to `string`.

---

This is what I simplified it to:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.Serializable()]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot("root", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Root
{

    [XmlElement("element", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("element", typeof(string), Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ElementType")]
    public string Element { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public ElementType ElementType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("secondElement", typeof(string), Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
    [XmlElement("secondElement", typeof(string))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("SecondElementType")]
    public string SecondElement { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public SecondElementType SecondElementType { get; set; }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable()]
[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ElementType
{
    element,
    [XmlEnum("http://example.com/ns:element")]
    nsElement,
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable()]
[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum SecondElementType
{
    secondElement,
    [XmlEnum("http://example.com/ns:secondElement")]
    nsSecondElement,
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If you have an actual supplied `xsd` to describe the XML then I'd suggest using that rather than writing new ones from scratch. The one's I've supplied are practically the minimum to be able to run `xsd` successfully. Somehow I doubt it though since this looks more the XML is being produced by someone not really understanding XML, namespaces, schemas, etc.